# Choosing custom template file in Symfony controller

Tags: symfony

I'm relatively new to Symfony, and currently using v 2.8.  I've been using the @Template annotation successfully like this:

```
/**
 * @Route("/editleague/")
 * @Template()
 */
public function editAction() {
  return $array;
}
```

And that successfully renders the twig template at Bundle/Resources/views/Default/edit.html.twig

I decided I want a different response (not a Twig template) if it was a post request, so just to start off, I changed the above code to:

```
/**
 * @Route("/editleague/")
 */
public function editAction() {
  return $this->render("Default/edit.html.twig",$array);
}
```

But I get a 500 error.  I've tried various combinations, but haven't gotten anything to work where I can control the rendered template in the function itself.  I believe it's a simple issue that someone with more experience will be able to figure out in seconds.

Comment: In your example, the variable `$array` is not defined (but that's probably due to a bad example in your question, right?). So please show what the log of your application is telling you about the error and/or visit it in the dev environment and tell us what is shown there.

Comment: Yeah, $array is defined, I just left that part out to focus on the parts that changed between the two.  I can't believe I forgot to check the development mode.  When I do that, it says:  Unable to find template "Default/edit.html.twig".  Wha would be the location then, i followed (I think) the same idea as listed on [the symfony page](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#rendering-templates).

Comment: Ah, I understand. Just take a look at @Paulpro's answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your template is in your bundle's Resources directory, you should use the Symfony logical name in your call to render:

```
'AppBundle:Default:edit.html.twig'
```

or:

```
':Default:edit.html.twig'
```

[See the difference](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/best_practices/templates.html#template-locations) between paths to templates stored in a bundle versus templates in your `app` directory.

Comment: To provide some additional context: The Symfony Best Practice is store templates under `app/Resources/views`. So when the documentation uses something like `render('Default/edit.html.twig')`, the referenced template will be searched for in `app/Resources/views/Default/edit.html.twig`. However, when you store your templates in your own bundle, you need to use the namespaced syntax given by @Paulpro. So `AppBundle:Default:edit.html.twig` translates to `src/AppBundle/Resources/views/Default/edit.html.twig (the actual location might differ depending on where your bundle is located).

Comment: Ok... it looks like this fixed it for me and I better understand template locations.  Thanks!  Changing "Default/edit.html.twig" to "Default/edit.html.twig" to "Bundle::Default/edit.html.twig" did it.